# How can we change the color of drawables added in android picture-in-picture mode

Tags: android, android-picture-in-picture

I have added a black color check icon drawable in my Picture-in-Picture mode.It is black in color and in pip window it is appearing in white color like other default pip icons(setting icon,cross icon).

I alse have tried passing a red color icon and it is also turning to white.

Is it possible to show icon on PIP window like the way it actually appears?

Following is the code I have added for adding icon to my PIP window

```
internal fun updatePictureInPictureActions(
        @DrawableRes iconId: Int, title: String, controlType: Int, requestCode: Int) {
    val actions = ArrayList<RemoteAction>()

    // This is the PendingIntent that is invoked when a user clicks on the action item.
    // You need to use distinct request codes for play and pause, or the PendingIntent won't
    // be properly updated.
    val intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this,
            requestCode,
            Intent(ACTION_MEDIA_CONTROL).putExtra(EXTRA_CONTROL_TYPE, controlType),
            0)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val icon = Icon.createWithResource(this, iconId)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            actions.add(RemoteAction(icon, title, title, intent))
            mPictureInPictureParamsBuilder.setActions(actions)
            setPictureInPictureParams(mPictureInPictureParamsBuilder.build())
            var result = enterPictureInPictureMode(mPictureInPictureParamsBuilder.build())
            Log.i(TAG, " result of enterPictureInPictureMode - " + result)
        }

    } else {
        TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < M")
    }

}
```

[image: screenshot]

I have added the screenshot of my PIP window for reference.